# what is easing logic in ng2-page-scroll?

Tags: angular

I am using ng2-page-scroll in my angular project for scrolling to specific location hash in my angular project.While going through the documentation of 'ng2-page-scroll' there is an option called 'pageScrollEasingLogic' I couldn't figure out the usage of that option.Could anyone help me understand the usuage of the easing logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pageScrollEasingLogic is meant to adjust how your page scroll animation is like. For example, when you click on the header, it starts slow and suddenly accelerates to the section chosen on the page. However, I do not know how to manipulate the variables given on the website  ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-page-scroll#service ). Thus, I am just using the equation given on the page. Just put it in and you will see the effect. Hope this helps.